# Difference in interface between data: and data?:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Could anyone tell me what is difference between these two?
`interface Car { data: any }`
and this
`interface Car { data?: any }`

Comment: `?:` indicates an optional field (can be `undefined`). You could've just Google it ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Optional chaining - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: That is not an example of optional chaining, it denotes a Nullable Property in TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

The question mark notes that it is nullable property.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface Car { 
     data?: any 
 }
```

This indicates that data is optional for the `Car` object. Typescript won't complain if you are not passing the `data` field.